# On characters of unipotent groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, characters, unipotent-matrices

I was thinking about characters of unipotent groups, this is my question.
Let's define a unipotent group as an algebraic linear group formed by unipotent elements, where an element is called unipotent if it acts unipotently on some regular representation.
Let $U$ be a unipotent group and $g:U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ a character of $U$.
Since image of groups under homomorphisms are groups and the Jordan decomposition is preserved, we have that $g(U) \subset \mathbb{C}^\times$ is a unipotent subgroup. But, the only unipotent subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is $\{1\}$. Therefore, we have only the trivial character. Is this argument right?

Comment: I made it, thanks. Actually, in my question I was thinking about matrices.

Comment: Do you require a character to be algebraic?

Comment: Yes, I require it to be an homomorphism of algebraic groups